# How to send user input to terminal from java program (i.e by programmatically)?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, terminal, sudo

I am executing command from java program like

```
Process myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo cat /etc/sudoers"); //It asks for password so I send password through outputstream from my program.

InputStream inputStream = myProcess.getInputStream();
OutputStream outputStream = myProcess.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write("mypassword".getBytes()); // write password in stream
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

But problem is that, it again ask to me for password as I already send the password through outputstream from my program.
For solving this I tried so many times but not actually done.

By using shell script,I am able to provide password to terminal and my program works fine
but it is not the most flexible way.

Can you suggest me any way for providing password through my java program ? (instead of shell programming)

Comment: this is too much of working around for simple task. Just send the username/password to the command while calling it. Reade up on those commands for exact syntax

Comment: Did you try sending `\n` character after your password? It might be required by the external app you are running to end input with `CR` and/or `LF`.

Comment: May be terminal program  requires input in a definite format.

Comment: yes,I also try using '\n' character after password but problem remains same

Comment: @Ruju I'm trying to do something similar, can you provide the shell script you said is working fine for you?

Comment: I have worked on it long time back. You can convert the same authentication steps to shell script file and call that script file directly from java. It will work surely.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the `-S` option of sudo :

```
String[] cmd = {"/bash/bin","-c","echo yourpassword| sudo -S your command"}; 
Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd);
```

But I'm not sure it's recommendable.

I'm not the author, I found this there : http://www.coderanch.com/t/517209/java/java/provide-password-prompt-through-Java